# How can I find the user location using Estimote Beacons in Android

Tags: android, estimote, android-ibeacon

I need to find the user position using Estimote Beacons. Is it possible to find the user location using Estimote Beacons in Android?

Can any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: Searching for [previous discussion mentioning beacons and trilateration](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beacon+trilateration) might give some good ideas. I haven't tried trilateration myself and it can be quite inaccurate and problematic because of all kinds of reasons having to do with RF technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacon triggers your mobile.It is a transmitter not the receiver. Beacon gives you UUID, Major number and Minor number. So you can identify the particular beacon from these id's. Invoke the service to update your latitude and longitude upon receiving beacon signal.

P.S. Make sure you have access to GPS permission.

For more information refer - [Android Beacon Library Sample](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)